# Is it possible to solve this or it has infinite solutions?

Tags: geometry

How do you calculate the perimeter of the blue square?

[image]

Sorry, initially I misread the question.  It asks for the smallest possible perimeter. Therefore solved with optimisation.

Comment: more information needed

Comment: Obviously, the answer would be infinite.

Comment: You might be able to consider the limits on what the perimeter could be, by noting that the smallest blue-square side length is $10\over \sqrt 2$, and the largest is $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Pythagorean theorem. Assuming that all of the four triangles are identical, let us denote the long side by $b$ and the short side by $a$.

Then $a^2 + b^2=c^2$ where $c$ is length of any of the sides of the inner square. Moreover, we know that $a+b=10$ since that is the length of the bigger square.

Thus, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=100$.

Thus $c^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=100-2ab$.

Therefore $\text{perimeter of square}=4c=4\sqrt{100-2ab}$

Hence, given either $a$ or $b$, we could solve for the perimeter, since we have the equation $a+b=10$. However, I believe, as the question is currently written, there is not enough information to solve.

See proof #4 http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/.

Comment: @All: This answer was posted before the omission in the phrasing of the question came to light. I edited the question after the OP posted the clarification as an answer.